# How to generate 1 report with findbugs-maven-plugin?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, pom.xml, findbugs

I would like to generate one global xml report with findbugs plug-in. My tree :

```
pom.xml
 └── /project 1
      └── pom.xml
 └── /project 2
       └── pom.xml
```

and my parent pom.xml :

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
     <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.5.3</version>
     <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
                <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
                <findbugsXmlOutputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/findbugs</findbugsXmlOutputDirectory>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Actually the  command `mvn compile findbugs:findbugs` generate one xml report per project.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1):

Well, getting Maven to do things differently can be tough.

A workaround might be to use the [UnionBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/datamining.html#unionBugs) command to combine all your FindBugs reports in the end. The UnionBugs command seems to be based on [work by Peter Franza](http://www.peterfranza.com/projects/findbugs-unionbugs-ant-task/), who also explains the Ant task for this. The UnionBugs Ant task is part of standard FindBugs.

Here's [how to run an Ant task from Maven](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/). Since you are using Jenkins, you can also simply define an Ant step after your Maven step in the Jenkins job configuration.